# How to wait for a jQuery toggle to finish before running another function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, promise, method-chaining

I am missing something really obvious but I can't make one of my methods to wait until a jQuery toggle is done.

I have the following three methods:

```
const toggleContainer = function() {
  addAnswerContainer.toggle("slow");
};

const toggleButtons = function() {
  submitAnswerBtn.toggle("slow");
  cancelAnswerBtn.toggle("slow");
};

const changeText = function() {
  if( addAnswerContainer.is(":hidden") ) {
    addOwnAnswerBtn.text("Add your own answer" );
  }
  else {
    addOwnAnswerBtn.text("Hide adding answer");
  }
};
```

All I want to do is to have something like this to work:

```
const toggleUI = function() {
  toggleContainer();
  toggleButtons();
  changeText(); // executes too fast
};
```

The problem is that `changeText()` executes too quickly and every time it checks, the `addAnswerContainer.is(":hidden")` returns `false`, unless I `setTimeout` it for some seconds, which is not what I want. I tried with callbacks, also with Promises, but I just can't make it work. How can I make the `changeText()` to wait, until the `addAnswerContainer.toggle()` has done its job?

Comment: What errors did you get with the callback approach?

Comment: @AndrewL with the callback approach I didn't have any errors, but again it was too fast. But that is, because I made my own callbacks and I just realized that the jQuery toggle was also accepting a callback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[.toggle( [duration ] [, complete ] )](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

The optional second argument is the function to cal once the animation is done, so just call `toggle` with the desired callback. Promises are the best way to do something like this:

```
const toggleContainer = () => new Promise(resolve =>
  addAnswerContainer.toggle("slow", resolve)
);

const toggleButtons = () => new Promise(resolve => {
    submitAnswerBtn.toggle("slow");
    cancelAnswerBtn.toggle("slow", resolve);
});

const changeText = function() {
  if( addAnswerContainer.is(":hidden") ) {
    addOwnAnswerBtn.text("Add your own answer" );
  }
  else {
    addOwnAnswerBtn.text("Hide adding answer");
  }
};
```

Then call `.then` on the promises to chain asynchronous functions:

```
const toggleUI = function() {
  toggleContainer()
    .then(toggleButtons)
    .then(changeText);
};
```

Or if you want `toggleContainer` and `toggleButtons` to run at once, and only wait before `changeText`:

```
const toggleUI = function() {
  toggleContainer()
  toggleButtons()
    .then(changeText);
};
```

Comment: Yup, brilliant, this has solved the problem. Very interesting how it works, I am now trying to understand it.

Comment: Also when I saw your comment I realized that the jQuery toggle itself had a callback and I managed to make it work with that:

`const toggleUI = function() {
          addAnswerContainer.toggle("slow", function() {
            submitAnswerBtn.toggle("slow");
            cancelAnswerBtn.toggle("slow", function() {
              changeText();
            });
          });
        };`

But your solution was exactly what I wanted in the first place. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I may suggest a simple but smart approach following your if-else statements like so:

```
const toggleContainer = function() {
  addAnswerContainer.toggle("slow");
  return true;
};

const toggleButtons = function() {
  submitAnswerBtn.toggle("slow");
  cancelAnswerBtn.toggle("slow");
};

const ToggleIfTrue = () => {
  if(addAnswerContainer.is(":hidden") && toggleContainer) { 
    addOwnAnswerBtn.text("Add your own answer" );
  }
  else if (addAnswerContainer.is(!":hidden") && toggleContainer) {
    addOwnAnswerBtn.text("Hide adding answer");
  }
};
```

So this way the inner if-else statement only runs if the `addAnswerContainer` is set as `hidden` and the other way around with the  final else if statement

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem with this solution. The addAnswerContainer is always hidden now

Answer (score 0):

Can return `$.when` promise from the toggle function and use `promise()` of element objects to be resolved in `$.when`.

call next step in next `then()` of promise chain

Simplified demo

```js
const toggleComplete = function(){
   console.log('finished animation id #', this.id)
}

const toggleButtons = function (){
  // toggleComplete only needed for this demo
  let p1=$('#1').toggle('slow',toggleComplete).promise()
  let p2=$('#2').toggle('slow',toggleComplete).promise()
 
  return $.when(p1,p2)
}

toggleButtons().then(_=>console.log('all animations done')/* change text here*/)
```

```css
div{display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1">
One
</div>

<div id="2">
Two
</div>
```