# Get offsetTop of accordion after collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the absolute position of a clicked accordion title after it's clicked.

The problem is, that the accordion collapse movement of Bootstrap and my jquery are fired in pretty much the same momemt. What happens is that my jquery gets the offset *before* the accordion is collapsed.

After it is collapsed the title can have another `offsetTop` after the click.

Is there a way to star my jquery after the collapse or wait a little to let the accordion collapse and after that request the `offsetTop`?

```
const handle = document.querySelector('#handle');



const headers = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion')

   .forEach(el => {

       el.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {

           handle.style.top = `${e.currentTarget.offsetTop}px`;



   });

});
```

[Here is an example](https://jsfiddle.net/mihawk21/j47xnf5g/1/)

As you see in the example the dot move far way down if you first open the first section and after that open the second section.

If you click the second section for one more time it move to the right place

Comment: possible duplicate?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50429649/how-to-wait-for-a-jquery-toggle-to-finish-before-running-another-function

Answer (score 0):

If I under stand your question, you could use setTimeout() to wait for your animation to complete

Note, one problem is we are not setting wait time dynamic, so it may not feel as responsive.

```
    setTimeout(()=>{
        handle.style.top = `${e.target.offsetTop}px`;
    }, 200)
```

Comment: Now I get following error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetTop' of null

Comment: Try passing e in as an parameter to the anonymous function

Comment: @ThinkCode try my updated example. I noticed you should be using e.target as opposed to e.currentTarget

Comment: I just found out the same answer. It worked for my exampe page but somehow now in my live page. I will try out on write the full answer if I figuere it out. Thanks alot!